# Upgrading SQL Server 2000 to MySQL 5.1 using DTS - How solve DateTime problem?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server-2000, migration, data-migration

I'm trying to migrate from sql server 2000 to mysql by using DTS. That's the best tool I know yet.

But one a sql server tables has a column with datetime type, the DTS suggest the following sql code:

```
 `StartDate` long varbinary NULL, 
 `EndDate` long varbinary NULL,
```

It should be:

```
 `StartDate` DateTime NULL, 
 `EndDate` DateTime NULL,
```

I do change manually but the DTS doesn't accept the new script. IT says:

> HResult of 0x800040e14 returned
>       Unexpected error occurred. An Error result was returned without an error
>   message.

Comment: Please word your question better and provide more info.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the exact nature of the issue you're trying to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved the problem.

I followed the steps:

1. Change the suggested script replace long varbinary to datetime
2. Don't worry about any possible warning message which may rise up
3. This change will not reflect at Destination columns list which still display the type long varbinary
4. Go at Transformations, check out if columns has destionation relationships

If any problem happens, try:

1. At Transformations, click new
2. Follow the instruction providing all information about columns and the relationship you want to make.

That's it. Thanks anyway!